# Recursively unzip all subdirectories while retaining file structure

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, command-line, zip

I'm new to bash scripting, and i'm finding it hard to solve this one.

I have a parent folder containing a mixture of sub directories and zipped sub directories.

Within those sub directories are also more nested zip files.

Not only are there .zip files, but also .rar and .7z files which also contain nested zips/rars/7zs.

I want to unzip, unrar and un7z all my nested sub directories recursively until the parent folder no longer contains any .rar, .zip, .7zip files. (these eventually need to be removed when they have been extracted). There could be thousands of sub directories all at different nesting depths. You could have zipped folders or zipped files.

However I want to retain my folder structure, so the unzipped folders must stay in the same place where it has been unzipped

I have tried this script that works for unzipping, but it does not retain the file structure.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ "`find . -type f -name '*.zip' | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]

do
    find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -- '{}' \; -exec rm -- '{}' \;
done
```

I want for example:

folder 'a' contain zipped folder 'b.zip' which contains a zipped text file pear.zip (which is pear.txt that has been zipped to pear.zip a/b.zip(/pear.zip))

I would like folder 'a' to contain 'b' to contain pear.txt 'a/b/pear.txt'

The script above brings 'b' (b is empty) and pear both into folder 'a' where the script is executed which is not what I want. eg 'a/b' and 'a/pear.txt'

Comment: When you unzip a zip file, it will recreate directories (and the files within them) exactly as they are stored in said zip.  I am not sure I understand your question, seems like you want what zip does anyway...?

Comment: So the path is: `b/pear.zip`, then `b/` is zipped as `b.zip`? That's problematic. Is there only one level of zipped zips? Or more?

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes, I think you are right. I do want what zip does anyway, but recursively and also doing the same with unrar and unzip. Before, I was referring to how the specific example script was outputting, which is not doing that. - apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Nic3500 the problem with your script is that the working directory for `unzip` never changes. Everything is extracted to `.`. You need to specify `unzip -d dir` (or change working directory) for each different directory.

Comment: @dan There are two levels of zipping. (b) is a zipped directory containing  a zipped text file. 'a' contains b.zip, which contains pear.zip. b.zip when extracted gives (b) which contains pear.zip (b/pear.zip) and when pear.zip is extracted it become pear.txt. The two unzipping process, resulting in a/b/pear.txt. (a is the parent and isn't zipped to start with). It could be even more nesting of zipped folders. This was just the simplest example I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
    mapfile -td '' archives \
    < <(find . -type f -name '*.zip' -o -name '*.7z' -print0)

    [[ ${#archives[@]} -eq 0 ]] && break

    for i in "${archives[@]}"; do
        case $i in
            *.zip) unzip -d "$(dirname "$i")" -- "$i";;
            *.7z)  7z x "-o$(dirname "$i")" -- "$i";;
        esac
    done

    rm -rf "${archives[@]}" || break
done
```

- Every archive is listed by `find`. That list is extracted in the correct location and the archives removed. This repeats, until zero archives are found.
- You can add an equivalent `unrar` command (I'm not familiar with it).
- Add `-o -name '*.rar'` to `find`, and another case to `case`. If there's no option to specify a target directory with `unrar`, you could use `cd "$(dirname "$i")" && unrar "$i"`.
- There are some issues with this script. In particular, if extraction fails, the archive is still removed. Otherwise it would cause an infinite loop. You can use `unzip ... || exit 1` to exit if extraction fails, and deal with that manually.
- It's possible to both avoid removal and also an infinite loop, by counting files which aren't removed, but hopefully not necessary.
- I couldn't test this properly. YMMV.